# Skip line at match

Tags: awk

I am printing a multiline string `mstr` with colour codes defined in array `tseq[knam]`, with `knam` being a colour identifier (e.g. Blu:, Grn:, etc).

For instance, with the multiline string `mstr`,

```
mstr= "\n \
Grn: \n \ 
 Some green text \n \
 More green text \ n \
Blu: \n \
 Moving to blue text \n \
 With more blue text here"
```

to produce the text appropriately coloured

```
 Some green text
 More green text

 Moving to blue text
 With more blue text here
```

The following code identifies the colour and sets the appropriate colour code to `cpt`.  But has the problem that the line that contains the colour declaration (e.g. `Grn:`, `Blu:`) in also printed.

Thus I want to skip the value of `astr[i]` when `knam == str`.  How can I solve this ?

```
## Split with newline character, and store into array
nlines = split(mstr, astr, "\n")
str = astr[i] ; gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, "", str)
for (i = 1; i <= nlines; i++) {
  ## Capture KNAM from TSEQ[KNAM] and match with string ASTR[I]
  for ( knam in tseq ) {
    if ( knam == str ) { cpt = tseq[knam] }
   }
  print cpt astr[i] rst
}
```

I have introduced `continue`, and test `knam == str` again.

```
for (i = 1; i <= nlines; i++) {
  ## Capture KNAM from TSEQ[KNAM] and match with string ASTR[I]
  for ( knam in tseq ) {
    if ( knam == str ) { cpt = tseq[knam] ; continue }
   }
  if ( knam == str ) { print "" } else { print cpt astr[i] rst }
 }
```

Comment: I do not think it should be `continue`.  How were you planning to use it ?

Comment: I think a `next` should do it to skip to the next record. What I don't understand are the extra `\n \\`'s in your input string and the outer for-loop with the splitting. Each line already contains a newline. But you also haven't shown your complete code. Btw., the task looks very related to this one: [unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735244](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735244).

Comment: I actually think in needs to be a `break`.  For making the multiline string with `gawk`, I was forced to include `\n` to indicate a newline and `\` as a continuation character.  Is there any other way to construct a multiline string?

Comment: The outer loop iterates through the multiline string `mstr` line by line.

Comment: The task is very related but is here applied in the implementation of an awk function.